# Using mod_rewrite to rewrite site root

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to have relative links that are preceded with a forward slash (/) get rewritten with mod_rewrite to refer to the site root.

I have site:

```
http://localhost/mysite/
```

and I have numerous references, for example, in my css directory, formatted like such:

```
background: url('/img/background.jpg');
```

**I would like to use mod_rewrite to point that at:**

```
http://localhost/mysite/img/background.jpg
```

But right now, it is pointing to:

```
http://localhost/img/background.jpg
```

I apologize in advance if this is a no-brainer, but I'm new to mod_rewrite, and I have so far been unsuccessful in getting this to work!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good thing to do. It is duct-taping a mistake that should be fixed at its core.

By rewriting URLs this way, you risk breaking links in other sites on `localhost`, for example, and it is a long-term maintenance nightmare having to deal with URLs outside your site's root directory.

Consider using relative links in your CSS instead, e.g.

```
background: url('../img/background.jpg');
```

if the images are in a sibling directory of where your CSS style sheet is in.

Links in style sheets are always relative to the location the style sheet is in - not the HTML file that uses it. That makes it very easy to use relative links in style sheets.

Comment: Well, I inherited a rather large project that is already set up like this, so I am just trying to get it to work on my local dev environment. All url references, not just in the css, are formatted with a / to indicate the site root. So I just need to come up with a functional mod_rewrite to get that to work for me and reference localhost/mysite rather than localhost/ . It might just be duct-taping, but changing every url reference would be way too time intensive.

Comment: @skiin Why not set up a separate local site with its own web root then? Might be the better/cleaner way

Comment: I've tried setting up dev.mysite.com (editing hosts file and creating a virtual host in httpd.conf) but was unable to get that to work correctly, so, since a mod_rewrite would only be a couple lines of code, even if it's not the ideal solution, it would definitely help get me going!